# Sometimes when using VirtualBox the mouse "breaks". Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, mouse

When I'm setting things in settings many times I have a bug that my mouse doesn't respond. It's really annoying. It has an icon like when you're dragging something. I can't click anything and one solution is rebooting.

I've used the mouse in Windows 7, Elementary OS, Ubuntu and now Debian without any problems. I only have this problem when I'm using VirtualBox.

Now I did something that I can't understand, mashed every key on the keyboard so I could logout and login, but I don't know how I did that. I don't know the keybindings in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Debian Stretch hasn't been released yet and there could be a bug in it that is causing your mouse to not work properly in VirtualBox. For best compatibility, the version of VirtualBox that you are using should also be more recent than the version of the guest OS that you are running in it.

VirtualBox Display settings can have a maximum of 128MB Video Memory in the VirtualBox Settings window. You can add another 128MB video memory from the terminal to the guest OS for a total of 256MB. If you do this, the 256MB Video Memory will show up in VirtualBox in the Display Settings of the guest OS. I suggest that you do this and see if that stops the mouse from having an icon like when you're dragging something. Open the terminal and type:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Linux" --vram 256
```

where "Linux" should be replaced by the name of your Linux guest OS in VirtualBox.

For a USB mouse, *System* -> *Motherboard* -> *Pointing Device* should be set to *USB Tablet*. If you have enough hardware resources to give the guest OS more RAM and 2 CPUs instead of 1 CPU, you can try doing this and see if it makes any difference in your mouse's performance in VirtualBox.

You aren't having problems with your mouse except for in VirtualBox, so I don't think that there is anything mechanically wrong with your mouse.

Comment: Mouse was used in W7, elementaryOS, Ubuntu and now Debian without any problems. Its only when using VirtualBox.

I'll wait then, thanks for answer and editing my post, sorry for my grammar etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably pressing alt tab to switch out of the virtual machine. You cant type anything because the virtual machine still thinks you are pressing alt. Press alt again to fix this issue. That's why when you button mashed, you probably hit alt and solved this problem.